# Can Principal Component Analysis explain variation in social data due to other factors?

Tags: pca

I have a set of social data for 30 countries. The data is in the form of percentage change in answers to a survey question, asked at two points in time (i.e. UK showed 20% increase in positive answers to Q1). There are around 30 countries.

I hope to use PCA to determine how much of the variation seen in the social data is explained by other factors - specifically Human Development Index, Happiness index and ecological footprint.

Is PCA the best way to get my answer? If so, when I plug the data in, do I include the original social data? I've tried that but the first component is always explained 100% by the variation in that data set.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple linear regression should do the trick, actually.  PCA is most useful when working with a relatively large set of predictor covariates with abnormally large multicollinearity.

[Here is a great overview](https://shankarmsy.github.io/posts/pca-vs-lr.html) of the "PCA vs. Regression" question you may be struggling with.  The $R^2$ value of the regression output is an estimate of how much $y$ variance is explained by your predictor variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link, it's really helpful. PCA appealed to me because I understand it can incorporate multiple 'explanatory variables' at a time. Is this possible with linear regressions? I suspect the answer most close to the truth will probably be that the variation in answer to the social questions may be explained by a combination of the explanatory variables, rather than just one.

Comment: It is called "multiple linear regression."  It regresses multiple explanatory variables against one or more dependent variables.